# How to optimize this in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have table structure as displayed in first table.

And want to fetch Both Male and Female Counts in a single query so that request will go only for one time onto the server.

[image: How to optimize this in MySQL ?]

Comment: Please note I know how to fetch all the data. But I want to do this by using optimization

Comment: +1 Thank you for clearly showing the input and the desired output.

Comment: We can also add 
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['gender'] . '<br />' . $row['count1'] . '<br />' . $row['count2'] . '<br />' ; 
}
to get the output

Comment: ![More siplified][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/rsmpy.jpg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

```
select gender,
       count(case when age between 0 and 20 then 1 else null end) Age_0_20,
       count(case when age between 21 and 40 then 1 else null end) Age_21_40
from yourtable
group by gender
```

Adjust accordingly :)

**Update, with clarifications**

Note that `COUNT` aggregate function only counts non-null values. Thus, the `else` values in the `case` must be `NULL`. The `When` value returns `1` but it could just be any non-null value.

Some people implement this by using `SUM`:

```
select gender,
       sum(case when age between 0 and 20 then 1 else 0 end) Age_0_20,
       sum(case when age between 21 and 40 then 1 else 0 end) Age_21_40
from yourtable
group by gender
```

The result is going to be absolutely the same.

Comment: Its returning error **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'than 1 else 0 end) Age_0_19, sum(case when age between 20 and 40 than 1 e' at line 2**

Comment: Did you just write `than` instead of `then`?

Comment: Oops! Sorry. I wrote **than** in place of **then** because it was already giving error **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by gender' at line 4**

Comment: Adrian's example is missing a FROM clause.

Comment: @pilcrow Thanks for the heads up, the hurry made me miss it! That's fixed now